# Using Passed Variable to Select Items like "Me.myvar.Item"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a new function that I can pass variables to and those variables will be used to select and modify items.

Function

```
Function TabDisplay(Switch As String, TargetTab As String)
    If (Me. & Switch & .Value) = -1 Then
        Me.Tabs.Pages.Item("TargetTab").Visible = True
    ElseIf Me.Switch.Value = 0 Then
        Me.Tabs.Pages.Item(TargetTab).Visible = False
    Else
        Me.Switch.Value = "0"
    End If
End Function
```

How I call the function

```
TabDisplay "SoftwareInstallable", "tabSoftware"
```

Working Code that I used before attempting this function

```
 If Me.SoftwareInstallable.Value = -1 Then
     Me.Tabs.Pages.Item("tabSoftware").Visible = True
 ElseIf Me.SoftwareInstallable.Value = 0 Then
     Me.Tabs.Pages.Item("tabSoftware").Visible = False
 Else
     Me.SoftwareInstallable.Value = "0"
 End If
```

**====Final Code====**

Function

```
Function TabDisplay(Switch As String, TargetTab As String)
   If Me.Controls(Switch).Value = -1 Then
        Me.Tabs.Pages.Item(TargetTab).Visible = True
    ElseIf Me.Controls(Switch).Value = 0 Then
        Me.Tabs.Pages.Item(TargetTab).Visible = False
    Else
        Me.Controls(Switch).Value = "0"
    End If
End Function
```

Function Call

```
TabDisplay "SoftwareInstallable", "tabSoftware"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want.  But let me describe it with a different example.

I have a form with a text box named *txtFoo*.  So I can `Debug.Print` its value to the Immediate window like this ...

```vb
Debug.Print Me!txtFoo.Value
```

Later I decide I want to store the control name in a variable so that I can `Debug.Print` the value of any other control simply by changing the variable.

```vb
Dim strControlName As String
strControlName = "txtBar"
```

Then I can use that variable to reference the matching item in the form's `Controls` collection, and obtain its value.

```vb
Debug.Print Me.Controls(strControlName).Value
```

I think you can use that approach to accomplish what you want, but I won't attempt to rewrite your code sample because I suspect I would get it wrong.

Comment: Exactly what I was going for. I know several other scripting/programming languages so I knew the basic concept behind how to do it but my lack of VB experience was making it very difficult for me to find relevant information on google. Thank you for your time & help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Consider a different name for your function's first argument.  `Switch` is also the name of a function.

Comment: Feel free to submit your revised code as an answer.  And you can accept that answer instead of this one when the system allows.  It seems you upvoted my answer, and that's good enough for me.  :-)